# My Android Qt creator doesn't work well

Tags: android, qt

Cannot overwrite file /home/marco/.config/org.kde.necessitas/toolChains.xml: Permission denied

This is the error that it shows whenever I try to do certain actions like open Qt (it does it 3 times and uses the file qtcreator.xml instead of toolChains.xml) or change some settings or close Qt. I changed the permissions for both files so that the admin which is me could do anything with the files but nothing prevented this error.

So what do you think is the best I can do?

btw this is the video I was following ([link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=suPeZ7XC1xk)), I only got the middle and this error happend and I am using ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you ran the Neccesitas installer as root or otherwise caused the permissions to be wrong (of course maybe this could also be caused by a bug in the installer, since it's still beta).

Check the following locations and see if they have proper read/write permissions for the current user (marco):

- /home/marco/.config/org.kde.necessitas/toolChains.xml
- /home/marco/.config/org.kde.necessitas
- /home/marco/.config

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, A friend of mine helped me, The problem was that root was the owner so as soon as I changed the owner of those files to me, everything worked. Thanks again